# Continuity of derivative implies differentiability at a point

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ is an open interval, $a\in I$ and $f:I\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose also that $f$ is diffble on $I-\{a\}$. Show that if $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)=s$ exists, $f$ is diffble at $a$ and $f'(a)=s$.

I honestly don't know where to start. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is

continuous in $[a,a+\epsilon]$ and $[a−\epsilon,a]$,

differentiable in $(a,a+\epsilon)$ and $(a-\epsilon,a)$;

apply the mean value theorem to estimate
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Comment: $f$ is differentiable in $(a,a+\epsilon)$ and $(a-\epsilon,a)$

Comment: I don't get it. But I applied L'hospital's rule and it seems to work